# PushNotificationsAPI: Failed to register device: NOKResponse(error=Unauthorized)

Tags: android, kotlin, push-notification, pusher

I am using Pusher Beams for sending notification to my users. It worked fine but today I got this error, and I don't know how to solve it.

```
PushNotificationsAPI: Failed to register device: NOKResponse(error=Unauthorized, description=The device token provided could not be validated against any known credentials)
```

This is my code:

```
private fun setPusherBeam() {
    try {
        val tokenProvider = BeamsTokenProvider(
            BuildConfig.PUSHER_BEAM,
            object : AuthDataGetter {
                override fun getAuthData(): AuthData {
                    return AuthData(
                        headers = hashMapOf(
                            "Authorization" to getHawkString(AUTH_TOKEN)
                        ),
                        queryParams = hashMapOf()
                    )
                }
            }
        )

        PushNotifications.setUserId(
            DbHelper.getUser()?.user_id.toString(),
            tokenProvider,
            object : BeamsCallback<Void, PusherCallbackError> {
                override fun onFailure(error: PusherCallbackError) {
                    Timber.i("BeamsAuth Could not login to Beams: ${error.message}")
                }

                override fun onSuccess(vararg values: Void) {
                    Timber.i("BeamsAuth Beams login success $values")
                }
            }
        )
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        Timber.i("BeamsAuth ex ${ex.localizedMessage}")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After 2days of struggling with this error, finally, it resolved due to these steps.

1-stop the API

```
PushNotifications.start(applicationContext, BuildConfig.INSTANCE_ID)
PushNotifications.stop()
PushNotifications.removeDeviceInterest("example")
PushNotifications.clearDeviceInterests()
```

2-clear android studio cash and reset it

3-remove the app from mobile and reinstall it

4-replace code from step1 with this

```
PushNotifications.start(applicationContext, BuildConfig.INSTANCE_ID)
PushNotifications.addDeviceInterest("example")
```

5-repeat 2 and 3

Comment: I can't ask users to delete and reinstall the app, is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the generated `values.xml` under `app\build\generated\res\google-services\debug\values`, then delete the app and build again. Took me a while to figure this out.